# passing variable from child view to its parent view just like element in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, view, extend

I have a child view file that contain

```
<!-- src/Template/Posts/view.ctp -->
<?php
    $this->extend('/Common/view');
    //1
    $this->assign('title', $post);
    //2
    $this->start('sidebar');
    //...
    $this->end();
?>
```

and its parent that contain

```
    <!-- src/Template/Common/view.ctp -->
    <h1><?= $this->fetch('title') ?></h1>
    <?= $this->fetch('sidebar') ?>
```

I can pass string through methods 1,2.
but how can I pass variables from child view to its parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all those who tried to tell "This is IMPOSSIBLE"
In your child view set the variable like

```
$this->set('toParent' , $toParent);
```

and use it in your parent view easily like

```
$toParent = $this->get('toParent');
```

and as you can see this is POSSIBLE :)

Comment: There is no need to use `$toParent = $this->get('toParent');`, you can just use this variable just like it was set from controller.

Answer (score 1):

In the [MVC paradigm](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html), a view shouldn't pass variables to anything else, just parse and display variables given to it. Passing variables is the job of the controller.

With that being said, what you're maybe trying to achieve is to *render the output* of a block that exists in the parent view or layout from the child view. In this case you should use `$this->assign('blockname', $variable);` or the equivalent functions explained in [View Blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks).

Comment: contrary to your opinion, view can pass variables to other view elements like $this->element('helpbox', ['var'=>1]).so why can not pass variable to its parent view.I also know about assign but this is not my answer :)

Comment: Again, what you seem to be trying to achieve is against the principle, that's why it's not supported. Your more specialized view shouldn't return anything backwards other than rendered data. It shouldn't use variables to exchange information with the parent. Elements are slightly different from blocks in the sense they are isolated pieces of code that live outside of the flow. That's why you need to pass them some data when calling them, but not something the view will prepare. Also elements never return anything else than rendered data.